# What are the HTTP header identifiers for different OVH CDN cache locations?

Tags: cdn

When having a web hosting solution from **OVH** that includes their Content Delivery Network (**CDN**), and the OVH web hosting + [OVH CDN](https://www.ovh.co.uk/web-hosting/cdn.xml) are correctly configured, the **HTTP headers** of the served web site are changed.

An example:

```
X-Cacheable: Not cacheable: no-cache
X-CDN-Geo: lag
X-CDN-Geo-IP: 46.105.194.197
X-CDN-Any-IP: 46.105.199.116
```

One of the headers is the "**X-CDN-Geo**" that tells the geographical location of the server that actually serves the file.

Is there a list available of all OVH CDN-Geo locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find such an OVH CDN HTTP Geo header list.

So I started to create one using [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org) and Internet search engines:

```
X-CDN-Geo: ams == Amsterdam, Netherlands
X-CDN-Geo: ash == Ashburn, Virginia
X-CDN-Geo: atl == Atlanta, Georgia
X-CDN-Geo: chi == Chicago, Illinois)
X-CDN-Geo: dal == Dallas, Texas
X-CDN-Geo: fra == Frankfurt, Germany
X-CDN-Geo: lag == Los Angeles, California
X-CDN-Geo: lon == London, United Kingdom
X-CDN-Geo: mad == Madrid, Spain
X-CDN-Geo: mil == Milan, Italy
X-CDN-Geo: nwk == Newark, New Jersey
X-CDN-Geo: par == Paris, France
X-CDN-Geo: sea == Seattle, Washington
X-CDN-Geo: snj == San José, California
X-CDN-Geo: tor == Toronto, Canada
```

**Note #1:** Amsterdam and London seem to be down, they were found using search engines, but currently not included at `webpagetest.org`.

**Note#2:** Miami, Warsaw, Singapore, Tokyo and Hong Kong don't seem to be live: they were not found in search engines neither used at any of the `webpagestest.org` locations.